# typo3 solr: create a query with typoscript with facets for navigation menu

Tags: solr, typo3

Is it possible to create a typoscript with a query for solr ,so that RECORDS of a facet can be used for an HMENU?

Or should an USER_FUNC do that work?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a USER_FUNC and connect to solr directly without using the solr extension. The reason is performance as solr might be fast but a `USER_INT`as the solr ext is slow and shouldn't be placed on every page as menu.